# What is the meaning of the verb slip into in this text?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I want to know what the verb **slip into** means in this text

> The steps to obtain a solution are as follows.
>
> 1. Take the Laplace transform with respect to one of the two variables, usually t. This
>    gives an ODE for the transform of the unknown function. This is so since the
>    derivatives of this function with respect to the other variable **slip into** the
>    transformed equation. The latter also incorporates the given boundary and initial
>    conditions.
> 2. Solving that ODE, obtain the transform of the unknown function.
> 3. Taking the inverse transform, obtain the solution of the given problem.

This is the only meaning I found for this verb: to put on a piece of clothing

Comment: I only find it in that one book by Erwin Kreyszig. Nowhere else. It would be like: fit in or slot in, in terms of meaning.

Comment: @Lambie        This text is taken from Kreyszig's engineering mathematics book, but the meaning you said doesn't fit in my opinion

Comment: Sometimes we can use the verb 'slip' to mean 'pass without being noticed or appreciated', e.g. dairy material might slip into a vegan food product, and it seems (perhaps) as if the arrival or presence of the derivatives in the transformed equation is being specifically drawn to the reader's attention because they might not have appreciated that it happens. I am reminded of the French verb _glisser_ in this sort of situation.

Comment: Yes, that is what I said. There is ONLY ONE book with it: that one. slip into: find something in something unexpectedly. Why don't you email the author?

Comment: Kreyszig received his PhD degree in 1949 at the University of Darmstadt under the supervision of Alwin Walther. He then continued his research activities at the universities of Tübingen and Münster.

Answer (score 0):

["Slip into" can mean:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/slip+into)

> To place, insert, or load someone or something inside of something else. In this usage, a noun or pronoun is used between "slip" and "into."

This usage is a bit unusual: in your quote, the thing being inserted is the *subject* of the verb, and the person doing the inserting is omitted entirely. So there's no object between "slip" and "into," which isn't valid with this particular sense of "slip into." But it's still intelligible.